# How do I select a custom gmail label with special characters using imaplib in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, imap, imaplib, gmail-imap

I am trying to select one of my Gmail labels called "" Education/Email zum löschen/Emails zum löschen".

```
import imaplib

IMAP_SERVER = "imap.gmail.com"
EMAIL = "myemail"
PASSWORD = "myapppassword"

imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(IMAP_SERVER) 
imap.login(EMAIL, PASSWORD)

status, messages = imap.select(" Education/Email zum löschen/Emails zum löschen", readonly=True)
```

This gives the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\U0001f4da' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

When trying to encode it with "utf-7" just as I am receiving the encoded labels with the imap.list() command, I get the following error:

```
import imaplib
from imapclient import imap_utf7

IMAP_SERVER = "imap.gmail.com"
EMAIL = "myemail"
PASSWORD = "myapppassword"

imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(IMAP_SERVER) 
imap.login(EMAIL, PASSWORD)

label_to_select = imap_utf7.encode(" Education/Email zum löschen/Emails zum löschen") 
 status, messages = imap.select(label_to_select, readonly=True)
```

```
imaplib.error: EXAMINE command error: BAD [b'Could not parse command']
```

How would I be able to select the label with the emoji?

I've tried to search for solutions but could only find them as to how to deal with spaces in label names. Appreciate any help!

Comment: If the folder has spaces in it, it needs to be placed within quotes as well.

Comment: @Max Yes, I've already done that. My issue is with non ascii-characters because the label has an emoji.

Comment: Your code doesn't show you putting a quote around your label, eg `select("\" + label_to_select \"")`

Comment: A protocol trace could also be useful to see exactly what is being sent (`imap.debug = 5`).

Comment: The other thing to do is to do a .list() so you can see exactly at how google has encoded it.

Comment: @Max I think its only useful when passing a variable for the label selection in imap.select(). But I have also tested it and its giving me the same error as my first example in the post unfortunately, except that it reads "... in position 1: ..."

Comment: When running imap.list() this is the output for the label:
b'(\\HasNoChildren) "/" "&2D3c2g- Education/Email zum l&APY-schen/Emails zum l&APY-schen"'

Also if I use the imapclient to decode it with utf-7 it prints the emoji perfectly fine

Comment: Oh my, think I've finally found the error. Seems like I only tested this when running the encoded test string:
`status, messages = imap.select("'&2D3c2g- Education/Email zum l&APY-schen/Emails zum l&APY-schen'", readonly=True)`

But the quotes actually need to be switched, so the double quotes are inside the single quotes. If I only change that it works well. 

I've also tried to use `select("\" + label_to_select \"")` from another post on here before, but only with the decoded label name.

Comment: Thank you for all the help! @Max 
Really never thought the positioning of the single and double quotes would make the difference ^^ Especially because I already tried to use the code snippet before and it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

My main error was that I had the single and double quotes switched when using imap.select(). It's important that the double quotes are inside the single quotes. My final code down below (a little more complex since I want the user to enter the label name in a simple text file and then use that as the input).

```
# Encode the label with UTF-7
label_to_select = imap_utf7.encode(" Education/Email zum löschen/Emails zum löschen")

# Convert the encoded label to a string and remove the bytes formatting characters
label_to_select = str(label_to_select)[2:-1]

status, messages = imap.select(f'"{label_to_select}"', readonly=True)
```

this would work just fine too:

```
status, messages = imap.select('"&2D3c2g- Education/Email zum l&APY-schen/Emails zum l&APY-schen"', readonly=True)
```

If you need the encoded version you can call imap.list().

Comment: Right, the IMAP protocol only knows about double quotes.  :)  they are not interchangeable like they are in the Python language itself.